# How to convert a coldfusion website into Native Mobile application

Tags: android, iphone, coldfusion, cordova, appmobi

I have a coldfusion website running in my server.I have to develop an Mobile application say for iPhone/Android.(I am not mentioning mobile website).

I dono much about the native mobile development however I guess there is a possibility to achieve using phonegap and other cross platform dev tools.

Please suggest me how would I convert my website to native installable mobile application?

Comment: Ok,If not on Phonegap is it possible on other ways? like fetching the data from my website and displying it on the mobile app?

Comment: This is where having true separation of concerns comes in handy. If your application was structured so that the UI was independent of the backend you could then leverage your backend via a native app. Or if your UI was amenable to it, use phonegap or adobe air to generate a mobile app from your UI.

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap will allow you to convert a html application.

However ColdFusion is a serverside generated HTML and thus cant be converted using PhoneGap unless the entire application is html with ajax calls to ColdFusion for the data.

I dont know of any technologies that will allow you to convert a server generated html type language to a native app, I dont believe one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Appsgeyser.com for convering your HTML website into an app. All online and no  SDK to install.